# How do I echo the key or value from inside a multidimentional array without writing its key in the echo statement?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array and would like to call the key and the value separately, of individual levels inside the array.

Now with a normal array, I can do this by writing:

```
$example = array('one', 'two', 'three');
echo $example[0];
```

and this will return: `one`

However, when I try to do this with a multidimensional array like so:

```
$example = array(
'optionone' => array('one', 'two', 'three'),
'optiontwo' => array('a','b','c'),
'optionthree' => array(1,2,3)
);
echo $example[0];
echo $example[0][0];
```

Instead of echoing 'optionone' followed by 'one' I get nothing returned, and no error code.

When trying to see why this is happening by using:

```
var_dump($example[0)];
```

or

```
var_dump($example[0][0]);
```

`NULL` is returned.

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to correctly get/echo/call 'optionone' to return from the array as a string: 'optionone' without writing the name and how can I call the value 'one' without writing:

```
$example['optionone'][0];
```

I'm trying to create something where it doesn't know the key name, so it rather is going by the position of the keys but i would like to be able to return the key names at different points in the program but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Comment: `array_keys` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just get your associative keys into an array with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), so you can access them as a 0-based indexed array, e.g.

So with `array_keys($example)` you end up with the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => optionone
    [1] => optiontwo
    [2] => optionthree
)
```

Which you then can access as you want it:

```
<?php

    $example = array(
        'optionone' => array('one', 'two', 'three'),
        'optiontwo' => array('a','b','c'),
        'optionthree' => array(1,2,3)
    );

    $keys = array_keys($example);
    echo $keys[0] . "<br>";
    echo $example[$keys[0]][0];

?>
```

output:

```
optionone
one
```

Answer (score 1):

The outer array in your example is an associative array.  There is not value at index `0`.  If you need to get to to the first key in the associative array without knowing the name of the key you would need to do something like:

```
$example = array(
'optionone' => array('one', 'two', 'three'),
'optiontwo' => array('a','b','c'),
'optionthree' => array(1,2,3)
);
//get array keys into array
$example_keys = array_keys($example);
// get value at first key in $example array
$first_inner_array = $example[$example_keys[0]];
// get first value from first inner array
$first_value = $first_inner_array[0];


// Or to get an arbitrary value:
$x = ... // whatever inner array you want to get into
$y = ... // whatever index within inner array you want to get to
$value = $example[$example+keys[$x]][$y];
```

I would say that if you find yourself doing this in code, you probably have your data structured poorly.  Associative arrays are not meant to convey any sort of element ordering.  For example, if you changed your example array to this:

```
$example = array(
'optiontwo' => array('a','b','c'),
'optionone' => array('one', 'two', 'three'),
'optionthree' => array(1,2,3)
);
```

You would get a different value retrieved from above code even though the relationship between outer array keys and inner array contents has not been changed.

Answer (score 0):

not tested

```
 foreach($example as $f_array){
    foreach($f_array as $key => $val){ //iterate over each array inside first array
        echo $key; //should print 'optionone'          
        echo $val[0]; //should print 'one'
        break;
    }
 }
```